# django templatetag "unicode object does not support item assignment error"

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following templatetag

```
@register.inclusion_tag('profile/profile_list.html', takes_context=True)
def address(context, sort_parameter):
    request = context['request']
    sort = request.GET.get('s') or None
    path = request.get_full_path()

    if sort_parameter in path:
        pass
    elif not sort_parameter in path:
        if "?" in path:
            return (path + "&s=%s" % sort_parameter)
        else:
            print (path + "?s=%s" % sort_parameter)
            return (path + "?s=%s" % sort_parameter)
    elif sort:
        if sort != sort_parameter:
            return path.replace('s=%s' % str(sort), '')
```

and template as:

```
<li><a href="{% address 'foo' %}">foo</a></li>
```

Which I get in the print `/path/?s=foo`.

But in return I get " "unicode object does not support item assignment error"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `'`:

```
<li><a href="{% address foo %}">foo</a></li>
```

Comment: Now i get `VariableDoesNotExist at /path/   Failed lookup for key [request] in ....`

Comment: @tunavargi, Do you pass `request` to template?

Comment: yes sure.. I get the path from request. This happened after removed quotations

Comment: @tunavargi, I mean .. in `view`, did you pass as follow: `render(request, 'template', {'request': request})`?